# Excel Worksheet events don't fire when backgroundworker is running

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker that is running a heavy task. While it runs the user can do some stuff in the UI like change the value of an Excel cell. There are also events like WorksheetChange event configured.

Now when the backgroundworker is running, these events do not get fired until the backgroundworker completes its execution. Why is that so? Why is a separate thread blocking Excel events?

Comment: can you please add code ?

Comment: What are you doing in the backgroundworker? Do you manipulate Excel from there? Maybe show some code..

Comment: it was a stupid mistake on my end. I was disabling application events in the function the backgroundworker was calling.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake. The function that the backgroundworker calls was disabling the application events 
this.Application.EnableEvents = false;

Hence, until it completed its work the other events wouldn't fire